# Find smallest palindrome for given input string

Tags: java, algorithm

Given a string containing lower case english alphabets and question marks.

Replace question marks such that after the string is re-arranged it forms a lowest palindrome that is lexicographically smallest palindrome. If it is not possible return -1

**Example:**

```
input string = axxb??

Here, I will replace ?? with `ba` so string = axxbba
Re-arrange = abxxba = palindrome

Return answer as abxxba as this is lowest palindome possible.
```

**Constraints:**

```
Length of input string is 1 to 10^5
```

Here is my approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solve("axxb??"));// expected answer = abxxab
    System.out.println(solve("a?xy???"));// expected answer = aaxyxaa
}

public static String solve(String s) {
    // Find question marks, also find frequency of each letter
    Map<Character, Integer> tree = new TreeMap<>();
    String ans = "";
    int count = 0;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == '?')
            count++;
        else {
            tree.put(c, tree.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
            ans += c;
        }
    }
    // count letters which occurred odd times
    int odd = 0;
    int n = s.length();
    for (int e : tree.values()) {
        if (e % 2 == 1)
            odd++;
    }

    // Check if valid answer is not possible
    if (odd != count) {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            return "-1";
        else if (odd - count > 1)
            return "-1";
    }

    // Fill the missing letter to make it palindome
    for (char e : tree.keySet()) {
        int v = tree.get(e);
        if (v % 2 == 1) {
            ans += e;
            count--;
        }
    }
    // remove last item to get lowest palindrome
    if (n % 2 == 1 && count % 2 == 1 && ans.length() > 0) {
        ans = ans.substring(0, ans.length() - 1);
        count++;
    }
    // Fill remaining letters with a, as letter a forms smallest palindrome
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ans += "a";
    }

    // Get frequency of each letter.
    tree = new TreeMap<>();
    for (char e : ans.toCharArray()) {
        tree.put(e, tree.getOrDefault(e, 0) + 1);
    }

    // Finally build the smallest palindome
    ans = "";
    // Build the left half
    for (char e : tree.keySet()) {
        int len = tree.get(e);
        if (len == 1) {
            ans += e;
            tree.put(e, tree.get(e) - 1);
            len--;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++) {
            ans += e;
            tree.put(e, tree.get(e) - 1);
        }
    }
    // Build the right half
    String rev = "";
    for (char e : tree.keySet()) {
        if (tree.get(e) > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < tree.get(e); i++)
                rev += e;
        }
    }
    rev = new StringBuilder(rev).reverse().toString();
    return ans + rev;
}
```

My approach works fine, but fails with time out errors, when input string size is large.
What is the better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: For starters, don't use a O(log n) TreeMap to collect frequency info; use a O(1) HashMap, then at the end sort a List of its entries which is an O(1) operation due to n=27 max.

Comment: How can we test the performance is (not) good enough?

Comment: Avoid String-creations `ans += e' you already know the length of your result so you can do everything within an `char[] of this length.` (or use at least a StringBuilder (with size initalization of the result-size) to create `rev` and `ans` to avoid all the String-creations).

Comment: A note on terminology. An alphabet is an ordered collection of letters used in a given language. There is *one* English alphabet in common use today. English letters are letters, not "alphabets".

Comment: "My approach works fine...": it may handle the input test cases but it returns `-1` for the input `"??"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should never concatenate strings in a loop, use StringBuilder or fill a char array and create the string from it. This is because strings are immutable in Java, so each iteration a completely new String is created which makes it O(n^2) instead of O(n) to create a string of length n adding one letter at a time (unless the compiler would somehow optimize it).
2. You don't need map, a simple array is enough to count the frequencies.
3. You only need to build half of the string and then you can revert and concatenate to create the palindrome.
4. String.charAt(index) is accessing the underlying char array while toCharArray() actually copies the underlying array.

```
public static String solve(String s) {
    int[] letters = new int[26];
    int qm = 0; // question marks
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        if (s.charAt(i) == '?')
            qm++;
        else
            letters[s.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
    boolean skip = s.length() % 2 == 1;
    int middle = 0;
    for (int i = 25; i >= 0; i--) // go backwards to skip highest letter if odd
        if (letters[i] % 2 == 1)
            if (skip) {
                skip = false;
                middle = i;
                letters[i] /= 2;
            } else {
                letters[i] = (letters[i] + 1) / 2;
                qm--;
            }
        else
            letters[i] /= 2;
    if (qm < 0) // we had to use more question marks than we have => impossible
        return "-1";
    letters[0] += qm / 2;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++)
        if (letters[i] > 0)
            sb.append(String.valueOf((char) (i + 'a')).repeat(letters[i]));
    if (s.length() % 2 == 1)
        return sb.toString() + ((char) (middle + 'a')) + sb.reverse().toString();
    return sb.toString() + sb.reverse().toString();
}
```